# is there a way to remove duplication in this code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, code-duplication

i have a method that looks like this:

```
   private double GetX()
    {
        if (Servings.Count > 0)
        {
            return Servings[0].X;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
        {
            FoodDescriptionParser parser = new FoodDescriptionParser();
            return parser.Parse(Description).X;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and i have another method that looks like this:

```
  private double GetY()
    {
        if (Servings.Count > 0)
        {
            return Servings[0].Y;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
        {
            FoodDescriptionParser parser = new FoodDescriptionParser();
            return parser.Parse(Description).Y;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Is there any way to consolidate this as the only thing different is the property names?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? I can think of some neat ways to do it in .NET 4.

Comment: If you have many such properties, you can use reflection (PropertyDescriptor). Does tend to be slow and not worth if it's only 2-3 properties.

Comment: @sblom - 3.5 is the version of dotnet

Comment: I don't think the .NET version matters. The C# version matters a lot though. For example, Darin Dimitrov's answer depends on lambda expressions, which have been available since C# 3.0. In older versions you could do a similar thing with anonymous methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a separate `GetServing` method:

```
private Serving GetServing() {
    if (Servings.Count > 0)
        return Servings[0];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description)) {
        FoodDescriptionParser parser = new FoodDescriptionParser();
        return parser.Parse(Description);
    }
    return null;
}

private double GetX() {
    Serving serving = GetServing();
    if (serving == null) return 0;
    return serving.X;
}

private double GetY() {
    Serving serving = GetServing();
    if (serving == null) return 0;
    return serving.Y;
}
```

Comment: You can cut a line with `return (serving == null) ? 0 : serving.X`

Comment: +1. I like this a bit better than Dimitrov's lambda approach, because your way is more focused on the meaning, rather than the mechanics of the program.

Answer (score 9):

```
private double Get(Func<SomeType, double> valueProvider)
{
    if (Servings.Count > 0)
    {
        return valueProvider(Servings[0]);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
    {
        FoodDescriptionParser parser = new FoodDescriptionParser();
        return valueProvider(parser.Parse(Description));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
var x = Get(value => value.X);
var y = Get(value => value.Y);
```

Remark: `SomeType` is the type of `Servings[0]` which if I understand your code correctly should be the same as the type of `parser.Parse(Description)`.

Comment: Clever and clean, but I have a felling this is using a big hammer on a very small nail.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `parser.Parse()` returns the same class that `Servings[]` holds, you could create a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) of that type, for which both X & Y are zero. Then you could have a function that returns the first element of `Servings[]`, if it exists, or `new FoodDescriptionParser.Parser(Description)`, if `Description` exists, or, finally, that null object.  And gather the X or Y as needed.